# How does ProjectB know how to find the DLL of ProjectA (that has 'per build' AssemblyName) in runtime?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have the following project structure:

```
-Solution
   -ProjectA
   -ProjectB (has reference to ProjectA - projectreference tag that points to csproj of ProjectA)
```

Both projects have dynamic AssemblyName depending on build configuration. 
 Let's say that if I build with "Debug" config then the outcome will be: DebugProjectA.dll and DebugProjectB.dll. 
 After building in "Release" config, it's going to be: ReleaseProjectA.dll and ReleaseProjectB.dll. 
 Namespace of classes in ProjectA is always the same and starts with ProjectA.*

**My question is:** How does ProjectB know how to find the correct DLL of ProjectA in runtime? 
 To be more specific: How does it know the name of the referenced project's DLL (that changes in different build configs)?

My guess is that AssemblyName of ProjectA (of given build config) is somehow stored in ProjectB assembly file during the build. Is this correct? How does it work?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate a little why project reference is not likely to turn out well? I have this exact situation in my project with 3 different build configurations (different brands) and everything is working perfectly fine. That's why I was curious how exactly does it work. It certainly looks like it takes the ProjectA's AssemblyName (of current build configuration) and places it in the ProjectB's manifest. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct quote from the documentation on [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies):

> The runtime uses the following steps to resolve an assembly reference:
>
> Determines the correct assembly version by examining applicable
> configuration files, including the application configuration file,
> publisher policy file, and machine configuration file. If the
> configuration file is located on a remote machine, the runtime must
> locate and download the application configuration file first.
>
> Checks whether the assembly name has been bound to before and, if so,
> uses the previously loaded assembly. If a previous request to load the
> assembly failed, the request is failed immediately without attempting
> to load the assembly.
>
> Checks the global assembly cache. If the assembly is found there, the
> runtime uses this assembly.
>
> Probes for the assembly using the following steps:
>
> If configuration and publisher policy do not affect the original
> reference and if the bind request was created using the
> Assembly.LoadFrom method, the runtime checks for location hints.
>
> If a codebase is found in the configuration files, the runtime checks
> only this location. If this probe fails, the runtime determines that
> the binding request failed and no other probing occurs.
>
> Probes for the assembly using the heuristics described in the probing
> section. If the assembly is not found after probing, the runtime
> requests the Windows Installer to provide the assembly. This acts as
> an install-on-demand feature.

Of course, this includes projects referenced by the assembly.

**Edit to clarify the OP's comment:**

As you may see on the output window on visual studio during the build process, you may notice that all referenced projects get build first. Later, the final names of their assemblies get added to the main executable and that is how is able to identify them. That last part is not visible on the output.

Comment: Hi. I have seen this documentation part, but this is not exactly what my question is about :) The cited documentation explains how runtime tries to resolve an assembly (it already knows the assembly name it is looking for). My question is: How does it know the name if the referenced project has dynamic AssemblyName that changes with build configuration? As I mentioned in the question, my guess is that it stores the name of referenced project's AssemblyName of the same build configuration, but this is only a wild guess, so that's what I want to find out.

Comment: To answer your edit: So is my guess from the original post correct? Is AssemblyName of the referenced project stored in the assembly that references this project? And it happens during build right?